Does every nonempty open subset $O\subset \mathfrak{I}$ of a topology contain a nonempty closed subset?
Let $(X,\mathfrak{I})$ be a topological space. Does every nonempty open set contain a nonempty closed subset?
[$O\in X$ is open if $O\in\mathfrak{I};\ $ $T\in X$ is closed if $X\setminus T$ is open].
Obviously this is true in metric spaces, but I'm relatively new to topological spaces and I can neither find a counter-example, nor conjure up a proof.

The empty set is a closed subset of anything.

@spaceisdarkgreen thanks. I amended the question accordingly.

No, consider the Sierpinski space. It has two points $a,b$, and the non-empty open subsets are $\{a\}, \{a,b\}$. The open subset $\{a\}$ does not contain any non-empty closed subset.

Thanks. I think I was getting muddled between different things...

No, and Martin Brandenburg has provided an example of such. But, if the space is $T_1$, then it is true, as points are closed. In fact, it is also true for $R_0$ spaces, as, in such spaces, each open set contains the closure of each point that it contains.
